# Publish interactive Office 2010 PivotChart to web, without Sharepoint?

Tags: web, excel-2010, ms-access-2010, pivot-table, powerpivot

Does anyone knows a way to publish my PivotTables and PivotCharts made in Excel, Access, or PowerPivot 2010 to a web page and maintain the interactivity?

I know this was possible in Excel 2003, but cant find a way to do the same in Excel 2010 without having to use Sharepoint and Excel Services.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In terms of PowerPivot based files this isn't possible.
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest and easiest option would be to put the dataset in Azure or Azure Marketplace and have them query the data directly via the PowerPivot plugin. Other than that you can not maintain the interactivity of the pivot chart online. It's not part of your question but I would suggest taking a look at a http://www.highcharts.com/ or http://d3js.org/ implementation. You can interact with an example here: 
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic (click jsfidle)

If you get to the point where you can justify the cost of having powerful reports online you can take a look at http://spotfire.tibco.com/demos at our last company we had so many requests for pivot tables and their charts to be accessible online that we ended up having to buy a Spotfire license :/
Good luck!